# how to bring out data out from def

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, file, tkinter

I have tried this code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


def browseFiles():
   open_f = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.xls')
   path_f = open_f.name
   print (path_f)


window = Tk()
windowWidth = window.winfo_reqwidth()
windowHeight = window.winfo_reqheight()
positionRight = int(window.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(window.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)
window.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))
window.title('Choose Your Excel file')
window.geometry("300x100")
window.config(background = "white")    
button_explore = Button(window, text = "Browse Files",height=2,width=20,command = browseFiles 
                 ,bg='white')
button_explore.place(x=75,y=20)
window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()

print (path_f)
```

It was able to plot in the first case but not in the second one. It was able to plot only in defined function and it is getting erased comming out.

```
C:/Users/Dell/OneDrive/Pictures/Untitled.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/sample.py", line 25, in <module>
    print (path_f)
NameError: name 'path_f' is not defined
```

please can anyone guide

Comment: `return path_f` from the fuction and store it in a variable? You are using the function as callback - so you may need to create a globally accessable thingy that you can set to it

Comment: Returning is not possible exactly because it is a callback function. Making the global variable is the best choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `path_f` is created inside the function, it belongs ONLY within the function(local variable), so what you can do is, make it global by saying `global path_f`:

```
def browseFiles():
   global path_f
   open_f = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.xls')
   path_f = open_f.name
   print(path_f)
```

Now `path_f` can be used anywhere within the code, given that it is defined before using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply declare `path_f` to be a global variable as follows:

```py
def browseFiles():
   global path_f
   open_f = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.xls')
   path_f = open_f.name
   print (path_f)
```